# Should "microsoft-excel" tag be changed to "spreadsheet"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Occasionally, we get a question asking about financial functions in spreadsheet programs.  Traditionally, these are called Excel sheets and Excel functions, but really most spreadsheets (including Google Sheets) use the same functions.

Most recently, this question was asked:

[How to calculate the number of months until a loan is paid off (given principal, APR and payment amount)?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/64639/10997)

The question specifically mentions Google spreadsheets.  I wanted to tag the question [spreadsheet](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet), but I see that the only spreadsheet tag that currently exists is [microsoft-excel](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel).

There are only 15 questions currently on that tag.  I'm wondering if the tag would be better named as [spreadsheet](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet), to include all the spreadsheet programs in use, including Google Docs, Open Office, etc.

Any strong feelings one way or another?

Comment: Most people do seem to explicitly mention Excel in their questions. I guess we could have both tags but that feels like overkill for 15 questions. I think just having spreadsheet is reasonable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree, Ben. There's Google, and there's also Open Office, and others, I'd imagine. No need for this tag to remain a brand, better to offer the generic word for the product.

Done. The new [spreadsheet](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet) tag has replaced [microsoft-excel](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel).

The [microsoft-excel](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) synonym needs to be voted on -

https://money.stackexchange.com/tags/spreadsheet/synonyms

Comment: I suggest anybody asking spreadsheet questions, though, continue to mention in the question body the exact product they're using. Not all functions/features are available everywhere.

Comment: I'd suggest making it a synonym, otherwise the tag can appear again at any time.

Comment: Did Ganesh figure out how to do it with ["health-savings-account" and "health-spending-account"](http://money.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms)?

Comment: Done! The screen to use wasn't obvious. Other mods helped me find it.

Comment: The synonym is now live. (Though I *would* suggest using `open-office-calc` rather than `open-office`, but that's somewhat unrelated.)

Comment: People were using the tag "open office" when they meant the spreadsheet part. There's no "open office calc" to merge.